# open HTML page in java Midlet using NetBeans 7.2.1

Tags: java, midlet

As school project I need to develop a java Mid let that will ask for a URI. Then the
application will make an HTTP connection using the given URI and retrieve a HTML
page, and display it to the user.
I am able to give the HTML link but it displays the HTML code when I run the application. 
i am using java net beans 
Thanks, any help is really appreciated

Comment: So basically you want a Browser?

Comment: J2ME doesn't support HTML rendering by default. You'd have to resort to using an external library for HTML rendering or render the UI yourself.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually need is to open native browser and show HTML page in it. This can be done using platform call:

`getInstance().platformRequest("http://bombusqd.hdd1.ru/m/")`

`getInstance()` is a method of `MidLet`.

Comment: Midlet is not supporting getInstance() for me